# JavaScript click in li by other parameters than class/id

Tags: javascript, click

I have a `<li>` with many attributes, one of them is data-id.
How can I click the `li` that have a specific data-id? (for example data-id="4052").

I can get the attribute, but I can't simulate the click there.

The example of HTML is:

```
<li tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="description of image" aria-checked="false" data-id="4000" class="attachment save-ready">
```

The only unique id is `data-id`.

Comment: you could use the `[data-id="4000"]`query selector to get the element using `document.querySelector`

Comment: In the normal click handler you can also put a conditional check for that data attribute’s value. If its not equal to 4052 then return else execute the logic.

Comment: @shrys it's supposed to be used like this? document.querySelector(`[data-id="${data}"]`).click(); . I have used it and I have an error. data is the var that have the id.

Comment: What is the error? a fiddle that works https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/v0xtn5fa/

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'click' of null" . But other clicks behind are working good. Maybe it's because the time it takes to other clicks that can't click it?

Comment: it could mean that the element isn't in the DOM (maybe `data-id` does not match?), in which case you could put a check if you've got an element with `.querySelector` in the first place and then proceed with `.click()`

Comment: Yeah, I think it takes too long and the element isn't in DOM yet. There's a proper way to make a click, wait until renders OK, make another click and wait again until renders, etc etc?

Comment: sure, you could use `DOMContentLoaded` event function for the clicks, and if the DOM elements are taking time to load you maybe could put your `click` login in `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selector `li[data-id='4000']` to target the `li` with `data-id` equal to 4000:

```js
$("li[data-id='4000']").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="description of image" aria-checked="false" data-id="4000" class="attachment save-ready">
Some li content
</li>

<!-- Different li-->
<li tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="description of image" aria-checked="false" data-id="4001" class="attachment save-ready">
Some other li content
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `click` event on data-id and use if condition to `check` specific id.

```
$("[data-id]" ).on( "click", function () {
        let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if(id == 4000){
            // handle your logic here
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
    } );
```

```js
$("[data-id]" ).on( "click", function () {
        let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if(id == 4000){
            // handle your logic here
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
    } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="description of image" aria-checked="false" data-id="4000" class="attachment save-ready">AAA
```

Comment: Maybe I don't get it well. I want to click it automatically based on data-id, not to thrigger something when I click it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if  you want to use only js to do this you can use 
`document.querySelector("li[data-id='300']").addEventListener( // the rest of code )`

or if you know where is the li

`<li   onclick="myFunction()"> <li>`